# C# WEBApi MVC Help pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom route below and action.

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.Route("Sites/{id:string}/Cache")]
    public ResponseMessage<Result> DeleteCache ([FromUri] string id)
    {
```

and when I got the the help page it gives three examples to use this call:

```
DELETE Sites/{id}/Cache
DELETE Sites/{id}
DELETE api/Sites/DeleteCache?id={id}
```

I'd like to keep the first one and remove the others. Is there a built in way to do this?

Here is my WebApiConfig.cs snippit....

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DeleteCache",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/Cache",
    defaults: new { controller = "Sites", action = "DeleteCache" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "help page"? Is that a page you wrote or something generated (like from Swagger)?

Comment: have you tried to modify the WebApiConfig.cs file?

Comment: @gunr2171 The `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage` package.

Comment: @AntoOne Yes, you can see my routes above now.

Comment: Are you sure that those other two routes trigger your action? They don't look related at all.

Comment: @gunr2171 They are related. I've updated it above to you see the relation, it's the action name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HelpPage will list every valid route for each controller. If you want a route to not apply to a specific controller you have to add contraints to the route to make it not match anymore :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new {controller = "((?!Sites).)*" }
);
```

This uses a negative lookahead regex to match every Controllers not named Sites

Comment: Thanks for this, it appears to work opposite of what I want. I want `DELETE Sites/{id}/Cache` to remain while removing the other two, it did the reverse though it is a lead to track down. If you can fix this I'll mark it as accepted answer. Lets see who fixes it first, you or I. :)

Comment: I was able to add `constraints: new { controller = @"^(?:(?!Sites).)*$" }` to remove a few.